# React-notification-system - trigger notification on JSON input

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs

Using `react-notification-system`, I am attempting to create a pop-up notification each time a JSON array is returned from the backend. For the sake of showing the issue I've manually added the array and parsed it in the below code.

As it appears I wish to trigger the event if the "type" of the `alerts` array is either "WARNING" or "ERROR", and furthermore print the message that comes along with it in the "message" part.

I'm pretty sure the issue I have is with the state and props. Right now, running this code, I am getting `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined` - Which leads me to the question, how do I access the information inside the array in React properly, and trigger it in the return function on the conditions?

Sample code:

```
var NotificationSystem = React.createClass({



    _notificationSystem: null,

    _addNotification: function(event) {

        event.preventDefault();
        this._notificationSystem.addNotification({
            message: 'Danger!',
            level: 'error',
            position: 'tc'
        });
    },
    componentDidMount: function() {
        this._notificationSystem = this.refs.notificationSystem;
    },

    render: function() {

        var mdata = {"alerts":[
            {
                "dateTime": 111111111,
                "message": "This is a super serious warning",
                "type": "WARNING"
            }
        ]};

        var mdataArr = Object.values(mdata);

        console.log(JSON.stringify(mdataArr)); // It prints the JSON in console

        if (this.props.mdataArr.type == "WARNING")
            this._notificationSystem.addNotification({
                message: this.props.mdataArr.message,
                level: 'warning',
                position: 'tc'
            });
        else if (this.props.mdataArr.type == "ERROR")
            this._notificationSystem.addNotification({
                message: this.props.mdataArr.message,
                level: 'error',
                position: 'tc'
            });

        return (
            <div>
                <NotificationSystem ref="notificationSystem" />
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you defined `mdataArr` in `render()` method itself, but you are looking for same in `this.props`

Try this in render method

```
    if (mdataArr[0].type == "WARNING")
        this._notificationSystem.addNotification({
            message: mdataArr[0].message,
            level: 'warning',
            position: 'tc'
        });
    else if (mdataArr[0].type == "ERROR")
        this._notificationSystem.addNotification({
            message: mdataArr[0].message,
            level: 'error',
            position: 'tc'
        });
```

Comment: Using your method, `console.log(mdataArr[0].type]` doesn't print any information?